# Open Source Java libraries for PDF to text conversion

Tags: java, pdf, text

I've heard about the [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), but is there another good tool for converting a PDF format into a text file (or word)? something that will give me bullet, numbering, title ,sub-titles, etc.?

If you know about something that is not for free, but is really good - it is still relevant!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted!

[PdfClown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/) is great! you should try it out. It let me get the text, the bookmarks, and attaching the text to its bookmark (even though it is not trivial though). No other library let me do this, the closest one was [Adobe's acrobat](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/10/20/accessing-pdf-with-acrobat-viewer-javabean.html), but it is very old and has no support.

so my choice is [PdfClown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/).

Answer (score 1):

I used [Itext](http://itextpdf.com/) and it work fine.

Comment: so, actually iText is good, but not good enough... it can convert to text, but it cannot tell me what is the titles, sub-titles, bullets/numbering etc..

Answer (score 0):

IcePdf is also one option to be considered as I believe.

Comment: AFAIK, icePDF cannot convert to text. it can render PDF to an image.

Comment: As per the product description,  http://www.icepdf.org/product/overview.html ->  PDF Content Extraction
Use ICEpdf to extract PDF document meta-data, text, and images.